# JSON: getElementById returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

I have a text input where I write a barcode it returns the name and the price from the database.

My code looks like this:

View:

```
<script>
function showProduct(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
                var jsonObject =  JSON.stringify(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("nameHint").innerHTML = jsonObject["name"];
                document.getElementById("priceHint").innerHTML = jsonObject["price"];
}
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/getproduct/q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
{{ Form::open() }}
{{Form::text('barcode', null, ['onchange'=>"showProduct(this.value)"])}}
<div id="nameHint></div>
<div id="priceHint></div>
{{Form::close}}
```

The controller:

```
public function getProduct($id){
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $sql = DB::select('select * from inventory where barcode = ?', [$id]);
    $name = $sql[0]->name;
    $price= $sql[0]->price;

    echo json_encode(array("name"=>$name, "price"=>$price));
}
```

When I write the barcode it shows: `undefined` where it had to show the name and the price. What I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a JSON string (`this.responseText`), you want a JavaScript object (`jsonObject`). You want to use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which turns a JSON string into a JavaScript object, instead of [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), which does the reverse, turning a JavaScript object into a JSON string.

```js
var jsonObject =  JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                // ^-- here
```

Comment: I tried it, but I got `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 44 of the JSON data` in the console and everytime I write a barcode in the cell the divs are blank

Comment: @Feralheart What's the exact value of `this.responseText`?